# Quicksort - stackoverflowerror

Tags: java, recursion, quicksort, stack-overflow

Apparently the sort method is causing a stackoverflowerror. Why?

```
    public static void quickSort(int[] a, int low, int high) {
        if (a.length > 1) {
            int middle = a.length / 2;
            int size = a.length - middle;
            int pivot = a[middle];

            sort(a, low, middle, high);
            quickSort(a, low, middle);
            quickSort(a, middle + 1, high);
        }
    }

    public static void sort(int[] a, int low, int middle, int high) {
        boolean b = true;

        int i = low;
        int j = high;
        for (int x = 0; x < middle + 1; x++)
            if (a[x] <= a[middle])
                i++;
        for (int x = middle + 1; x < high + 1; x++)
            if (a[x] > a[middle])
                j--;
        if (i != middle && j != middle + 1) {
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
            b = false;
        }
        if (b == false)
            sort(a, low, middle, high);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your partition function (you called it `sort`). The recursive call should be converted to a loop. But there are other problems as well.

Comment: I think you implement algorithm wrong. There is no `sort` call inside sort. Which algorithm are you implementing?

Comment: I couldn't really understand any of the algorithm 100% so i implemented mine.

Answer (score 0):

note here in sort function.

```
if (b == false) {
  sort(a, low, middle, high);
}
```

this b always false. and you do no change in low, middle, hifg values. so sort function call recursive as it is. so no change at all, function call repeat and stackoverflow will occure.

Comment: **always** use `{` and `}` for conditional blocks, especially with one liners!

Comment: Each time i call the method b will become true, and i only change it to false if a swap occurs

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski thanks for your suggestion. here after i will fallow this

Comment: @RoudyTarabay but swap occurs every call. **Check your stacktrace**